# Transfer BrickOwl wishlists to BrickLink

Tags: bricklink, brickowl

Is there an easy/automated way to transfer BrickOwl wish lists to BrickLink? I have wishlists on BO for each incomplete set I own and would like to move them over to see if BL can complete them cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using rebrickable.com.
Here's a more detailed guide:
http://rebrickable.com/blog/2015/bricklink-brickowl-integration
In case you have an LDD version of the model you wish to build, check out my question [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/7047/is-there-a-step-by-step-guide-to-extracting-a-parts-list-from-ldd-to-bricklink).