# Is there a step-by-step guide to extracting a parts list from LDD to bricklink?

Tags: ldd, bricklink

I'd like to build a model I have in LDD, but i don't know how to get my parts list (I exported BOM) into [bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/). I know there is [rebrickable](http://rebrickable.com/), but I don't see an option to import either `.lxf` or `.xlsx`... A link or guide would be very helpful.

Comment: Wanted Bricks is Windows only, anything for OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great program that takes an LDD file and makes it an .xml file:
http://www.nolberger.se/lego/wantedbricks/
From there you can copy the text and paste it into your bricklink wanted list.